# postcode or postal code?

Tags: word-choice

As I understand it, both `postcode` and `postal code` mean the same thing.
How do I decide which one to use ?

Is there any reason to use one over the other ? Are there slight differences in meaning ? Or is it perhaps a UK grammar vs US grammar decision ?

Thanks!

---

> I'm a software developer and need to add this field as a database column, so in the end I'll go with either `postcode` or `postal_code`

Comment: In the United States, the standard term is Zip Code, although the meaning is still clear for either of these.

Comment: We say "postcode" in Australia, but as Paul said, either term is clear.

Comment: In the UK we say postcode, but people would probably understand postal code.

Comment: For internal software, use whichever term is used in the country where the software is being developed and maintained.
For user-visible names, the software should adapt to the user's locale.
So in the USA, say "Zipcode" (#####), in Canada say "Postal Code" (A#A     #A#), in Australia say "Postcode" (####), etc.
Given the different formats in each country, the user interface needs to be customized anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is less a grammar question and more a question of which terminology is used by the postal system in a particular country - for instance, in the UK this is a Post Code, in the US a Zip Code, in Canada a Postal Code, and so on. If you are developing for a specific country it would be best to use whichever term is used in that country. Wikipedia has [a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_code) of some country-specific synonyms, though I imagine it is not exhaustive:

CAP: Italy

CEP: Brazil

Eircode: Ireland

NPA: French-speaking Switzerland and Italian-speaking Switzerland

PIN: India

PLZ: Germany, Austria, German-speaking Switzerland and Liechtenstein

Postal code: Canada

Postcode: Many English-speaking countries and the Netherlands

PSČ: Slovakia and Czech Republic

ZIP code: United States and the Philippines

If you are developing for multiple countries at once you will have to either pick a term that makes sense for you or design a way that users see whichever is appropriate for where they are based.

Comment: Strictly speaking, these are not synonyms, as each of them is a technical term standing for the codes of one particular country, except *postal code* and *post code*, which will readily be understood as generic, when used in a context that is not country-specific.

Comment: "in the UK this is a Post Code" - strictly speaking, I believe "postcode" (one word, lowercase) is preferred. As in [Wikipedia: Postcodes in the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom). `royalmail.com` (the UK postal service) uses the compound term "postcode" almost exclusively (99.8%) on its website, there are only a few instances of "post code" (and just a couple "postal code"). Searching Google for "post code" with a _UK locale_ returns "postcode" as a _suggestion_.

Answer (score 4):

To directly answer your question: When deciding on your database schema, you could use either `postcode` or `postal_code`.

An English speaker would be just as likely to understand either phrase, especially when looking at the context and the contents of the field.

That being said, although Wikipedia is not an authoritative source, the community on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_code) seems to have settled on **Postal Code**.

Answer (score -4):

"postal" is a regular English word. "Postcode" is not in my reference dictionary as a word, although it may be in some.

"Post" as a synonym for "mail" is chiefly British English, according to my Webster's New World Dictionary

Keep in mind other meanings of "post" == a place where someone is stationed, a solid vertical rod, and a prefix meaning "after" ("post-doctoral work")

The whole point is to avoid ambiguity and confusion, right? So either is probably fine for a database label.

In the US, they are called "zip codes."

Comment: 'Either is probably fine' is an unsuitable answer on ELU. Which is/are idiomatic?

Comment: Whether **postcode** is in your dictionary of choice or not is irrelevant to the question, as it _is_ commonly used and widely understood.Dictionaries as references for the "validity" of a word often "lag" the actual usage of a word in the language.

Comment: In any case [Onelook](https://onelook.com/?w=postcode&ls=a) gives about 20 dictionaries with **postcode**.

Comment: We're talking about a label in a database, not a speech before parliament, for pete's sake.

Comment: Which dictionary are you using? It's in all the online dictionaries I checked.

Comment: As mentioned in my post, Webster's New World Dictionary. It's been the recommended reference of the AP Styleguide that journalists use, that's why it's my go-to.